# What just didn't happen with NASA's Moon-to-Mars directorate?

Tags: nasa, cost, government, artemis-program

The Spacenews.com article [Sirangelo leaves NASA after exploration reorganization scrapped](https://spacenews.com/sirangelo-leaves-nasa-after-exploration-reorganization-scrapped/) says:

> WASHINGTON — A former space industry executive who joined NASA to guide its revamped lunar exploration strategy has left the agency after just a month and a half.
>
> In an internal memo May 23, NASA Administrator Jim Bridenstine announced that Mark Sirangelo had stepped down as a special assistant to the administrator after a proposed reorganization of the agency was rejected by Congress.
>
> That reorganization would have created a “Moon to Mars Mission Directorate” incorporating parts of the existing Human Exploration and Operations Mission Directorate (HEOMD) and Space Technology Mission Directorate. Bridenstine announced plans to create the directorate in March, when Vice President Mike Pence set the goal of landing humans on the moon by 2024, saying it would “focus on the formulation and execution of exploration development activities.”

**Question:** What information (if any) is available about the nature of the proposed directorate?  Was it to have been a "second NASA" reporting to the US government, or would it likely have reported directly to the "main" NASA <s>director</s> administrator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Directorate is a high level branch that reports to an associate admin who reports to the administrator. Here's a NASA org chart showing the Directorates at center

[image]

If it had happened, there would have been an additional red box there in the center.

Presumably, Mr. Sirangelo was intended to head up the new Directorate:

> Subsequent to our completing  two of these goals, the initial Moon
>   2024 technical path and President’s Budget amendment last week, the
>   response back from Congress indicating their lack of support for
>   establishing a new agency level Moon Mission Directorate was certainly
>   disappointing. Following that, from our discussions, I understand that
>   your decision is to not to implement any alternative Agency level
>   reorganization and to retain the Agency structure, as is, with any
>   future management changes to remain internal to HEO Directorate. From
>   this I realize that that my planning role is complete and without a
>   logical follow-on I would now like to focus on having a positive
>   transition.

[Source of org chart](https://www.orgcharting.com/nasa-org-chart/)

[Mr. Sirangelo's resignation letter](http://www.parabolicarc.com/2019/05/25/mark-sirangelos-resignation-letter/)